# AWS Lambda + API Gateway routing best practice

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

In a AWS Lambda + Api Gateway context, what are the best practices for routing requests? Let's say we want to have different responses based on path and request method.

- Make a single catch-all lambda handler on `$default` route and use `event.rawPath` + `event.requestContext.http.method` to return different result based on path + method.
- Make a different dedicated API Gateway Route with a different dedicated handler for each desired route and method.

I will provide a short example using javascript and aws-cdk

**Single handler method**

```js
// stack.js
class MyStack extends Stack {
    const handler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'default')
    new LambdaRestApi(this, 'Api', { handler })
}

//stack.default.js
export async function handler(event) {
    const path = event.rawPath
    const method = event.requestContext.http.method
    let body
    switch (path) {
        case '/hello':
            if (method === 'POST') {
                body = 'Response to "POST" request from "/hello"'
            } else if (method === 'GET') {
                body = 'Response to "GET" request from "/hello"'
            }
            break
        case '/goodbye':
            body = 'Response from "/goodbye"'
            break
    }
    return { statusCode: 200, body }
}
```

**Api Gateway Routes method**

```js
// stack.js
class MyStack extends Stack {
    const helloGETHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'hello-get')
    const helloPOSTHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'hello-post')
    const goodbyeHandler = new NodejsFunction(this, 'goodbye')
    const api = new RestApi(this, 'Api')
    const hello = api.root.addResource('hello')
    const goodbye = api.root.addResource('goodbye')
    hello.addMethod('GET', new LambdaIntegration(helloGETHandler))
    hello.addMethod('POST', new LambdaIntegration(helloPOSTHandler))
    goodbye.addMethod('ANY', new LambdaIntegration(goodbyeHandler))
}

//stack.hello-get.js
export async function handler() {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: 'Response to "GET" request from "/hello"'
    }
}

//stack.hello-post.js
export async function handler() {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: 'Response to "POST" request from "/hello"'
    }
}

//stack.goodbye.js
export async function handler() {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: 'Response from "/goodbye"'
    }
}
```

Apparently, these two approaches provide the same possibilities and I am being confused on which one to adopt. Some downsides of the single-lambda-catch-all approach I can think of are

1. Size of the single handler getting out of control in bigger applications
2. Impossibility to use API Gateway Authorizers

But, in an application which is small and doesn't need authorizers, can this be any good? Are there other things I am not considering? How does this apply to cost effectiveness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no silver bullet. Try to think from several perspectives:

1. AWS Limits. For example. there are 1K concurrent lambdas per account. This is a soft limit and you can request more.
2. Security. You may need Authorizers for some methods.
3. Cold starts. Having a lambda per method may negatively impact cold start time.
4. [S.O.L.I.D.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) and [Well-Architect](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/well-architected/) principles. Lambda meant to be a simple function-unit-of-scale.
5. Monitoring. What is your plan on keeping the whole system in a good health?

Personally I tend to keep lambdas small (1 lambda per method) and use ApiGateway routing capabilities. Also I have alarms on lambda failures. Having it setup this way let me get fine-grained notifications and spot issues faster.